# Testing REST API endpoints

Tags: c#, .net, rest

I have a number of REST api endpoints that I am calling via ajax from a web  client, and I want to write some automated tests to insure that they work properly outside of a web browser.

I am writing them as unit tests Tests and here is what I have so far:

```
[TestClass]
public class ApiTests
{
    string local_host_address = "http://localhost:1234//";

    public async Task<string> Post(string path, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> parameters)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0,0,5);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var response_message = await client.PostAsync(local_host_address + path, new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters));
            var response = await response_message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            if (response_message.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return response;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Request failed");
            }
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    [TestCategory("ApiTests")]
    public void TestLogon()
    {
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        parameters["email"] = "bob@aol.com";
        parameters["password"] = "rosebud";

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var output = Post("Default.aspx/Logon", parameters);
            Console.WriteLine(output.Result);
        }).Wait();
    }
}
```

...pretty basic, it just tries to call a specific endpoint, and return the results. Problem is, this call returns the basic default.aspx web page body, not the results generated by default.aspx/logon. I am doing something wrong, but I have been over it with a debugger and I cannot see my error. The default.aspx/logon endpoint exists and it works perfectly when I access it via website. Am I missing or overlooking something?

**SOLUTION:**

Bruno's alteration of my code snippet works quite nicely. Anyone else trying to solve the problem of testing a REST endpoint can just put that into a unit test and pass in a POCO and it will return the JSON response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are sending the body as FormUrlEncoded although you marked your request as application/json.

If your API is REST and takes JSON, instead of taking the *Dictionary*, you could deserialize an object (e.g. with Newtonsoft.Json):

```
    public async Task<string> Post<T>(string path, T data)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

            var response_message = await client.PostAsync(local_host_address + path, new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var response = await response_message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            if (response_message.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return response;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Request failed");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I created an Web API that is accessible through local IIS. How can I make it externally available? Thanks.